# Change isEnabled visual state for datepicker

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-store-apps

I am trying to change the `DatePicker` visual state in a Windows Store App so that when the `DatePicker` is disabled, it is not as transparent as it usually is when an element is disabled. So far this is what I have:

```
<Style x:Key="DateDueStyle" TargetType="DatePicker">       
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DateDuePicker" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The issue is that if I set my `DatePicker` style to use this style, the entire `DatePicker` disappears. Am I doing something wrong with the visual state?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have removed the entire template.

In your code the DatePicker now consists of an empty Grid inside a Border.

Start by selecting your Date Picker -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy, then further improve the control by adding visual states.